# How to Create an HTML Template?

Tags: html, templates

**Problem**

I have a collection of images with linked captions on a page. I want them each to have identical HTML.

Typically, i copy and paste the HTML over and over for each item. The problem is, if i want to tweak the HTML, i have to do it for all of them. It's time-consuming, and there's risk of mistakes.

**Quick and Dirty Templating**

I'd like to write just one copy of the HTML, list the content items as plain text, and on page-render the HTML would get automatically repeated for each content-item.

**HTML**

```
<p><img src=IMAGE-URL>
<br>
<a target='_blank' href=LINK-URL>CAPTION</a></p>
```

**Content List**

```
IMAGE-URL, LINK-URL, CAPTION
/data/khang.jpg, https://khangssite.com, Khang Le
/data/sam.jpg, https://samssite.com, Sam Smith
/data/joy.jpg, https://joyssite.com, Joy Jones
/data/sue.jpg, https://suessite.com, Sue Sneed
/data/dog.jpg, https://dogssite.com, Brown Dog
/data/cat.jpg, https://catssite.com, Black Cat
```

**Single Item**

Ideally, i could put the plain-text content for a single item anywhere on a page, with some kind of identifier to indicate which HTML template to use (similar to classes with CSS).

```
TEMPLATE=MyTemplate1, IMAGE-URL=khang.jpg, LINK-URL=https://khangssite.com, CAPTION=Khang Le
```

**Implementation**

Templating systems are widely used, like [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/) and [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) on the server side, and Mustache on the client side. This question seeks a simple, single-file template solution, without using external libs.

I want to achieve this without a framework, library, etc. I'd like to put the HTML and content-list in the same .html file.

Definitely no database. It should be quick and simple to set it up within a page, without installing or configuring additional services.

Ideally, i'd like to do this without javascript, but that's not a strict requirement. If there's javascript, it should be ignorant of the fieldnames. Ideally, very short and simple. No jquery please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is a complete solution. It's exciting to edit the HTML template in codepen and watch the layout of each copy change in real time -- similar to the experience of editing a CSS class and watching the live changes.

Here's the code, followed by explanation.

**HTML**

```
<span id="template-container"></span>

<div hidden id="template-data">
    IMG,, LINK,, CAPTION
    https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive.jpg,, khangssite.com,, Khang Le
    https://i.redd.it/jeuusd992wd41.jpg,, suessite.com,, Sue Sneed
    https://picsum.photos/536/354,, catssite.com,, Black Cat
</div>

<template id="art-template">
    <span class="art-item">
        <p>
            <a href="${LINK}" target="_blank">
                <img src="${IMG}" alt="" />
                <br>
                ${CAPTION}
            </a>
        </p>
    </span>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function LoadTemplate() {
    // get template data. 
    let sRawData = document.querySelector("#template-data").innerHTML.trim();

    // load header and data into arrays
    const headersEnd = sRawData.indexOf("\n");
    const headers = sRawData.slice(0, headersEnd).split(",,");
    const aRows = sRawData.slice(headersEnd).trim().split("\n");
    const data = aRows.map((element) => {
        return element.split(",,");
    });

    // grab template and container
    const templateHtml = document.querySelector("template").innerHTML;
    const container = document.querySelector("#template-container");

    // make html for each record
    data.forEach((row) => {
        let workingCopy = templateHtml;

        // load current record into template
        headers.forEach((header, column) => {
            let value = row[column].trim();
            let placeholder = `\$\{${header.trim()}\}`;
            workingCopy = workingCopy.replaceAll(placeholder, value);
        });

        // append template to page, and loop to next record
        container.innerHTML += workingCopy;
    });
};
```

New version on github:
https://github.com/johnaweiss/HTML-Micro-Templating

**Requirement**

As specified in the question, this solution is intended to optimize the coding experience on the HTML side. That's the whole point of any web templating. Therefore, the JS has to work a little harder to make life easier for the HTML programmer.

The question seeks a reusable solution. Therefore, JS should be ignorant of the template, fields, and data-list. So unlike @MisterJojo's answer, the template and all data are in my HTML, not javascript. The JS code is generic.

**Design**

My solution is based on the `<template>` tag, which is intended for precisely this usage. It has various advantages, like the template isn't displayed, processed, or validated by the browser, so it has less impact on performance. Programmer doesn't have to write an explicit `display:none` style.
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33089975

However, `<template>` tags are normally only intended for loading *content* into the layout. That's inadequate. This tool allows template variables *anywhere* in the HTML, including inside the tags (eg attributes like `<img src`).

**HTML**

My HTML has three blocks:

- **template:** The HTML coder develops their desired display-structure of the output, in real HTML (not plain text). Uses `<template>`
- **data:** The list of records each of which should be rendered using the same template. Uses `<span>` with a HIDDEN attribute.
- **container:** The place to display all the output blocks. Uses `<span>`.

**Template**

My sample template includes 3 placeholders for data:

```
${LINK}
${IMG}
${CAPTION}
```

But of course you can use any placeholders, any number of them. I use string-literal delimiting-style (although i'm not actually using them as string-literals -- i just borrowed the delimiter style.)

**Data Element**

The question specifies data should be stored in HTML. It should require minimal keystrokes.

- I didn't want to redundantly retype the fieldnames on every row. I didn't use slotting, JSO, Jason, or XML syntax, because those are all verbose.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots
- It's a simple delimited list. I eliminated all braces, brackets, equals, parens, colons etc.
- I put the fieldname-headers only on the first row. The headers are a visual aid for the HTML developer, and a key for Javascript to know the fieldnames and order.
- Record Delimiter: End-of-line
- Field Delimiter: Double-commas. Seems safe, and they're easy to type. I don't expect to see double-commas in any actual data. Beware, the developer must enter a space for any empty cells, to prevent unintended double-commas. The programmer can easily use a different delimiter if they prefer, as long as they update the Javascript. You can use single-commas if you're sure there will be no embedded commas within a cell.
- The data block is hidden using the `hidden` attribute. No CSS needed.
- It's a span to ensure it takes up no room on the page.

**JAVASCRIPT**

**Data**

The data is processed by Javascript with two split statements, first on newline delimiter, then on the double-comma delimiter. That puts the whole thing into a 2D array. My JS uses trims to get rid of extra whitespace as needed.

**Place-holder Substitution**

Handling multiple entries requires plugging each entry into the template.

i went with simple string-replacement instead of string literals.

**Multiple Templates**

New version which supports multiple templates, and ability to use same template in multiple locations on same page.

https://github.com/johnaweiss/HTML-Micro-Templating

**Future**

Inspired by @MisterJojo, an earlier version of my solution used **template literals** to do the substitution. However, that was a bit more complicated and verbose, and seemed to require use of `eval`. So i switched to `.replaceAll`. Yet template-literals seems like a more appropriate method for templates, so maybe i'll revisit that.

A future version may adapt to whatever custom field-delimiter the HTML developer uses for the data block.

The dollar-curly delimiter for placeholders is a bit awkward to type. So i'm interested in finding a less awkward non-alpha delimiter *that won't conflict with HTML.* Considering double-brackets or braces `[[NAME]]`

Maybe there are simpler ways to pull the data-table into JS.

I've read components work well with `<template>`, but i didn't go there.

Imo, the JS committee should develop a variable-placeholder feature for `<template>` tags, and natively accommodate storing the data in HTML. It would be great if something like this solution was part of the rendering engine.

Answer (score 1):

you mean [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ?

```js
const arrData = 
  [ { img: '/data/khang.jpg', link: 'https://khangssite.com', txt: 'Khang Le'  }  
  , { img: '/data/sam.jpg',   link: 'https://samssite.com',   txt: 'Sam Smith' } 
  , { img: '/data/joy.jpg',   link: 'https://joyssite.com',   txt: 'Joy Jones' } 
  , { img: '/data/sue.jpg',   link: 'https://suessite.com',   txt: 'Sue Sneed' } 
  , { img: '/data/dog.jpg',   link: 'https://dogssite.com',   txt: 'Brown Dog' } 
  , { img: '/data/cat.jpg',   link: 'https://catssite.com',   txt: 'Black Cat' } 
  ] 

const myObj = document.querySelector('#my-div')

arrData.forEach(({ img, link, txt }) => 
  {
  myObj.innerHTML += `
    <p>
      <img src="${img}">
      <br>
      <a target='_blank' href="${link}">${txt}</a>
    </p>`
  });
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! Is arrData JSON? Thx!

Comment: @johnywhy Almost, it's a JavaScript object (JSO), where the double quotes syntax is not required. In JSON it is mandatory because a JSON document is a simple text in UTF-8 and double quotes are used as delimiters (except for numeric types); and you have to use a JSON parser to transform that text into usable data. In JS it's the `JSON.parse()` command, and it produces  a JSO data. -- JSOs have more technical possibilities than JSONs, since they can contain methods.

Comment: Is there JSO equivalent of JSON.parse()?

Comment: @johnywhy `JSO` is a (rarely used) acronym for *J*ava*S*cript *O*bjects, `JSON` is a common abbreviation for [`"JSON format"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it is also a  JSGO (JS Global Object) named [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) (with different methods like [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [`JSON.stringify()`](JSON.stringify())). Please read the doc, and if possible mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Ok, so your arrData is already an object, and needn't be parsed, correct?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it doesn't fulfill the request to list data and fieldnames in the HTML file.

Comment: i upvoted your answer, btw.